# NameError - uninitialized constant FeedEntry::Feedzirra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feedzirra

I have a FeedEntry.rb which has this line in it:

```
class FeedEntry < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.update_from_feed(feed_url)
feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
end
```

When I try calling `FeedEntry.update_from_feed("http://feeds.feedburner.com/railscasts")` I get the following error:

```
NameError - uninitialized constant FeedEntry::Feedzirra:
  activesupport (3.2.14.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:520:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (3.2.14.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
  activesupport (3.2.14.rc2) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
  app/models/feed_entry.rb:5:in `update_from_feed'
```

I have the `gem 'pauldix-feedzirra'` in my Gemfile and ran bundle install. I can't figure out why the issue is. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gem 'feedzirra'` instead of `gem 'pauldix-feedzirra'` in my Gemfile fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your model:

```
require 'feedzirra'
```

Comment: That helped a bit. But now I get this error: `SyntaxError - .../gems/mdalessio-dryopteris-0.1.2/lib/dryopteris/sanitize.rb:101: too short escaped multibyte character: /\`|[\000-\040\177\s]+|\302[\200-\240]/:
 mdalessio-dryopteris (0.1.2) lib/dryopteris/sanitize.rb:101:in \`'
`

Comment: Also is there a reason why I would need to do `require 'feedzirra' even though I have the gem in my Gemfile and installed with with `bundle install`?